# Python Submodule Importing Madness

Tags: python, import, git-submodules

I'm banging my head against the wall with some basic Python importing. I have simplified the problem as much as possible hoping I'd be able to expand this to a larger scale if I understand how this works

**Here is the dilemma** -
`run.py` from inside the submodule `p1` works, but NOT when it's at the top level. Why?

(version Python 3.6.3)

---

### Structure:

```
/sandbox
    __init__.py
    /p1
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        run.py
    run.py
```

**/sandbox/p1/__init__.py**

```
__all__ = ["file1", "file2"]
```

**/sandbox/p1/file1.py**

```
from file2 import B
class A(object):
    pass
```

**/sandbox/p1/file2.py**

```
class B(object):
    pass
```

**/sandbox/p1/run.py**

```
from file1 import A
a = A()
```

**/sandbox/run.py**

```
from p1 import file1
a = file1.A()
```

Doing:

`python p1/run.py`  (works fine)
`python run.py`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "run.py", line 2, in 
>       from p1 import file1
>     File ".../sandbox/p1/file1.py", line 1, in 
>       from file2 import B
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'

Comment: is this module somewhere in your python (environment?) path? If it is not you need to make a relative import `from .p1 import file1`. If it is, you can import it with `from sandbox.p1 import file1`

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision

Comment: from p1 import file1 -> this line finds file1 and tries to import it. However file1 cannot import file2 although it's in the same path

Comment: `file1` should have `from .file2 import B` for the same reason

Comment: Thanks. Just tried this and something interesting happened. run.py in the top module works, but the p1/run.py will not.      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p1/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from file1 import A
  File "/Users/bogdan.culda/Desktop/workspace/sandbox/p1/file1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .file2 import B
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: It shouldn't work within the subdirectory - you're authoring a package.  It is meant to be imported by other stuff, not run on its own.  If you want it to be run on its own, look into [PEP0338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/)

Answer (score 1):

#### (I) no module named 'file2'

You encountered `No module named 'file2'` because you run `run.py` outside a package, when `file1` import `file2`, python cannot find `file2` as the module directory not in module search path.

For your scenario, `file1` & `file2` are 2 modules which in the same package, for this situation, suggest you use `relative import`, this is the best practice.

#### *file1.py*

```
from .file2 import B
class A(object):
    pass
```

Then, `python run.py` works.

#### (II) attempted relative import with no known parent package

As you mentioned you will see next if execute `python p1/run.py`:

> attempted relative import with no known parent package

What does it mean?

This because `relative import` can just be supported in the module which in package.

You may say `file1.py` is in package `p1`, why still see the error?

This is because python use `__name__` to determine if this module in package or not, not by the position of it.

Change `file1.py` as follows:

```
print(__name__)
from .file2 import B
class A(object):
    pass
```

Next is the output:

#### *python run.py*

> p1.file1

#### *python p1/run.py*

> file1

For `python p1/run.py`, because it runs in the package, python will fail to know it is in a package, so output is `file1`.

If `__name__` does not has `.`, python will think it's not in package, so relative import failure.

#### (III) Finally, what if you really want to execute `python p1/run.py`, e.g. unittest your package?

Use `python -m p1.run`, this should works to execute top script which inside a package.

Comment: Your description of the difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is incorrect. Python 2 and Python 3 both add the script's directory to the module search path; the difference is that Python 2 has implicit relative imports.

Comment: I mean module's current directory, not top script's directory.

Comment: How to understand OP's original error if we did not use `relative import`? Python2 is ok, but python3 will have error? Please teach me, thanks.

Comment: Python 2 does not add the module's directory to `sys.path`. What happens is that when the `p1.file1` module executes `from file2 import B`, Python 2 will first attempt to interpret that as `from p1.file2 import B`, and it will only look for a top-level `file2` module if it finds no `p1.file2`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, remove py2/py3 difference, thanks for teach me.

Answer (score 0):

Python makes it intentionally difficult to mix scripts in a modules. The way this can be handled is like this:

```
/project
    /scripts
        run.py
    /sandbox
        __init__.py
        /p1
            __init__.py
            file1.py
            file2.py
```

**/project/sandbox/p1/file1.py**

```
from .file2 import B
class A(object):
    pass
```

**/project/sandbox/p1/file2.py**

```
class B(object):
    pass
```

**/project/scripts/run.py**

```
from sandbox.p1.file1 import A
a = A()
```

I make sure that the path to `/project` is in a `.pth` file in the site-packages of the virtual environment I want to use it from.

## conda

If you use conda, you can use [`conda develop`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/build/conda-develop.html)