# Import a module from the parent directory within packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I've referred to several threads and articles including:

- [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)
- [Can't get Python to import from a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456481/cant-get-python-to-import-from-a-different-folder)
- [Import Script from a Parent Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951255/import-script-from-a-parent-directory)
- [PEP 328 -- Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

but can't get the desired result.

Say I have a directory called "helloworld":

```
helloworld
|--__init__.py
|--say_hello.py
|--another_hello
   |--__init__.py
   |--import_hello.py
```

This is say_hello.py:

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello World!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

This is import_hello.py:

```
from .. import say_hello
say_hello.hello_world()
```

I am hoping to *import `say_hello` module wherever I call `python /path/to/import_hello.py` without using `sys` module*.

However, now when I do `python /path/to/import_hello.py`, it will return `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`, and I have no idea why it isn't working.

Even this doesn't work:

```
from helloworld import say_hello
say_hello.hello_world()
```

It will give me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'`.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The top-level package has no parent.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I thought I was specifying the parent folder of where import_hello.py locates. In that case the parent should be the folder helloworld, isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Submodule Importing Madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129300/python-submodule-importing-madness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a script out of the middle of a package like that. When you do that, you're not running `helloworld.another_hello.import_hello` based out of `/path/to/helloworldsparent/`, you're running `__main__` based out of `/path/to/helloworldsparent/helloworld/another_hello`. So, it doesn't have a parent package to `import` as `..`.

---

You can run the module with `-m`:

```
$ python -m helloworld.another_hello.import_hello
```

… assuming `helloworld`'s directory is on your `sys.path` (e.g., because you've installed it into `site-packages`, or because your current working directory is its parent, or because you've set up a `PYTHONPATH`).

---

But a cleaner solution is usually to leave the deep modules alone and write "entry point" scripts at the top level that look like this:

```
import helloworld.another_hello.import_hello
helloworld.another_hello.import_hello.main()
```

If you're using `setuptools` (and you really should be for anything complicated enough to need two levels of packages), you can make it create the entry point scripts automatically at install time (or at `--inplace` time, during development). See [Automatic Script Creation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) in the docs (but you're probably going to need to read other sections as well to get the whole idea; the docs are pretty large and complicated).

Comment: Thanks. But I am not quite clear about what "leaving the deep modules alone" is when using `setuptools`. Does that mean I can leave import_hello.py as it is right now, i.e. `from .. import say_hello; say_hello.hello_world()`?

Comment: @ytu The `from … import` line will work, but you usually want to move your top-level code (that `say_hello.hello_world()`) into a function that can be called by someone after they `import helloworld.another_hello.import_hello`, rather than leaving it there to be run the first time anyone does that `import` in a process. In other words, you want modules, not scripts, inside packages.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Yet I keep failing to import modules in `import_hello` and getting `ModuleNotFoundError` with command created with console_scripts in entry_points of setup.py...

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can first try to add the parent path to the system path and then try using the import.

```
from sys import path as pylib
import os
pylib += os.path.abspath('..')
from helloworld import say_hello
```

Hope it helps !!