# python relative import module failed

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a file structure like the following:

```
root/
    v1/
    __init__.py
    example_1.py
    script/
        __init__.py
        classification.py
        prediction.py
        example2.py
```

classification looks like this:

```
#classification.py    
print(__name__)
from .prediction import predict_func
def func1():
    predict_func()
```

This works fine for example1.py that looks like this

```
#example1.py
from script.classification import func1
func1()
```

but import classification from example2.py like the following will fail

```
#example2.py
from classification import func1
func1()
```

because in the example2.py scenario `__name__` in classification would simply be `classification` rather than `script.classification` as example1.py, therefore there's no parent node here, hence the import module failed.

I know one of the solution is to add the script directory to sys.path in both example1.py and exaple2.py, and use `from prediction import predict_func` in classificationo. This will work in both example1.py and example2.py, but is this a good method, and is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Submodule Importing Madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129300/python-submodule-importing-madness)

Comment: Isn't it `from ..classification import func` in `example2.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `example_1.py` is in the `root` directory, this make me think that `root` is the source root of your project. So, this directory must appear in the Python path, ie: `sys.path`.

And, each directory which is under `root` should be a Python package. So, `script` must have a `__init__.py` file (usually empty).

You should take a look in the official Python tutorial about [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

**Edit**

In your second example (below) you try to import classification as if it is a root package but it is not.

```
# example2.py
from classification import func1
func1()
```

To fix that, you need to use relative import or a full package name:

```
# example2.py
from script.classification import func1
func1()
```

Of course, to run your example, you need to do:

```
python -m script.example2
```

Comment: I do have `__init__.py` in script and v1. I updated the structure. But this still doesn't solve the relative path problem.

Comment: @I-PINGOu. I edited my answer. Do you need clarifications? If not, you can [Vote on it and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just tested it and it works fine with `python -m script.example2` if I run the command from v1. But it does not work if I run the interpreter from root. I think that because -m option add current working directory to sys.path so script.classification works when cwd is v1